# Listen to video progress Flutter video Player plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Hi I'm using the flutter video player plugin, I have something similar like this `[{phrase:"something", startAt: 1039}, {phrase:"other something", startAt: 26500}]` is there a way to change in ui the phrase based on the start time while the video is playing.

I have try to use a timer with a duration of 100 ms and use a player controller reference `playerController.value.position.inMilliseconds` and find if a phrase start at this time to scroll to this but it didn't work.

How I can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the video plugin and I suggest you do the time comparison in seconds instead of milliseconds.
If you add a listener to your video plugin, unfortunately it won´t listen to it every millisecond, but it won´t fail the seconds count